# Нужно распарсить get запрос на Java и достать названия стран

Tags: java, json, веб-программирование, api, get

```
public class HhApi {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Console console = new Console();
        Console.console();
        HhApi hhApi = new HhApi();
        HhApi.hhApiCountriesList();

    }

    public static void hhApiCountriesList() {

        String hh = "https://api.hh.ru/areas/countries";

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(hh).openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(500);
            connection.setReadTimeout(500);

            connection.connect();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == connection.getResponseCode()) {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    sb.append("\n");
                }
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
            } else {
                System.out.println("FAIL :" + connection.getResponseCode() + ", " + connection.getResponseMessage());
            }
        } catch (Throwable cause) {
            cause.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Здесь варианты: 1) деселиаризируешь JSON и с каждого объекта читаешь name   2)парсиш строку с помощью регулярки  n)другой подход

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как с помощью GET запроса вытащить нужные данные?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/899426/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-get-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

С помощью регулярного выражения:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=name\":\")[^\"]+").matcher(sb);
while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());//here iterate by country
}
```

JSON Object:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(sb);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.println(jsonObject.optString("name"));//here iterate by country
  }
```

Comment: Какой JSON вы юзаете?

Comment: Я просто пример указал (вроде JSON.simple), а юзаю сейчас для сериализации\десириализации Jackson, он более гибкий в настройках